# How can I control the colour of multiple buttons in a form depending on a value?

Tags: vb.net, forms, button

I am creating a hotel booking system for a hotel with 31 rooms, so I have 31 buttons called "Button1", "Button2", etc.

I need to change the back colour of the buttons depending on availability of a room (red/green).

Each room has an "IsVacant" variable in the database that is either true or false and that value will be imported as an array into the form. I just need a way to link the colour of all buttons depending on the corresponding values of the imported array.

[Screenshot of Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lQn9.png)

Comment: Hello @Oliwier, which language is it ? **HTML ?** Then you should be using Javascript to achieve that. Which element of HTML-DOM do you use to display your data, how does it look like your code ? Please provide enough details to your question...

Comment: You can create the button base on the room available by using loop. You could add handler to these button to do things like booking, cancellation and etc. As for the colour, you can either change the colour when these buttons are collected or use the the Tag properties to do something about it. Do let me know if you need to know more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a class to hold you room data.

```
Public Class Room
    Public Property RoomNubmer As Integer
    Public Property IsVacant As Boolean
    Public Property Details As String
    Public Sub New(RN As Integer, Vac As Boolean, Det As String)
        RoomNubmer = RN
        IsVacant = Vac
        Details = Det
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return RoomNubmer.ToString
    End Function
End Class
```

In the form create a form level variable `List(Of T)` so the room data will be visible from anywhere in the form.

To fill the list we first connect to the database and retrieve the data. Next, loop through the `DataTable` rows creating a new room and adding the room to the list.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private RoomList As New List(Of Room)

Private Function GetRoomData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Rooms", cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub FillRoomList()
    Dim dt = GetRoomData()
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        RoomList.Add(New Room(CInt(row(0)), CBool(row(1)), row(2).ToString))
    Next
End Sub
```

In the `Form.Load` we fill the room list. Then make a list of Buttons. Assuming the length of the two lists is the same:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FillRoomList()
    Dim ButtonList As New List(Of Button) From {Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4} 'etc
    For i = 0 To ButtonList.Count - 1
        ButtonList(i).Text = RoomList(i).ToString
        If RoomList(i).IsVacant Then
            ButtonList(i).BackColor = Color.Green
        Else
            ButtonList(i).BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

As you can see, List(Of T) is just handy as a pants pocket for collections of things. Learn more about them in *[List<T> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0)*.

Answer (score 0):

1. loop for each button
2. query `IsVacant` from the database
3. change the back color of the button according to the query result